# Is there a recipe to use buildr to upload to maven central via ossrh?

Tags: buildr

Using maven, one can push artifacts to central via ossrh; this requires GPG signatures, source, and javadocs in addition to the usual maven-deploy-plugin of the core jar.

Is there a recipe to arrange all of this with buildr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do this in Apache ODE so that artifacts comply to Apache's release policy and are accepted by Nexus. I assume that OSSRH works similar.

The GPG task used in ODE is based on [a Buildr How-to document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BUILDR/How+to+upload+signed+artifacts+with+GPG) but is slightly extended to work. You can find it [here](https://github.com/apache/ode/blob/trunk/tasks/gpg.rake). To sign all artifacts before upload, simply add a `gpg_sign_before_upload` to your toplevel project (see [here](https://github.com/apache/ode/blob/trunk/Rakefile#L625) for an example).

Answer (score 1):

I have just gone and implemented this for several of my projects. Here is what I had to do.

Buildr includes a built in gpg addon but it seems to have a bug when an artifact does not have a pom so I had to drop in a [patch](https://github.com/realityforge/gelf4j/blob/master/tasks/gpg_patch.rake) to fix this. Then I created a custom addon that allows me to generate a pom as part of the build process that is available [here](https://github.com/realityforge/gelf4j/blob/master/tasks/custom_pom.rake). Then I simply add some metadata to the main buildfile as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/realityforge/gelf4j/blob/master/buildfile#L12-L18). So ignoring the bug fix patch and the custom addon. The following demonstrates the code required to add to the buildfile

```
pom.add_apache2_license
pom.add_github_project('realityforge/gelf4j')
pom.add_developer('realityforge', 'Peter Donald', 'peter@realityforge.org', ['Developer'])
pom.optional_dependencies.concat [:getopt4j, :slf4j_api, :log4j, :logback_core, :logback_classic]

...

package(:jar)
package(:sources)
package(:javadoc)
```

I then tend to add configuration for the release location either directly to the build file or more likely into a _buildr.rb file in the same directory as the buildfile that contains code similar to the following

```
repositories.release_to[:url] = 'https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/'
repositories.release_to[:username] = 'username'
repositories.release_to[:password] = 'password'
```

Hope that helps.